# Plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

After Android Studio's Kotlin plugin update, It stopped working. Plugin is getting disabled automatically. Below error I am getting.

```
com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: Duplicate registration for EP: org.jetbrains.uast.uastLanguagePlugin: original plugin com.intellij, new plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionsAreaImpl.registerExtensionPoint(ExtensionsAreaImpl.java:286)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionsAreaImpl.registerExtensionPoint(ExtensionsAreaImpl.java:128)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.registerExtensionPoints(IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.java:328)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.registerExtensionPointsAndExtensions(PluginManagerCore.java:1352)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1264)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1393)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.getPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponentConfigs(ComponentManagerImpl.java:302)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:95)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:425)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:411)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:206)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:343)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> To solve this issue, you have to either **upgrade or downgrade your kotlin plugin**

**Solution 1: Upgrade Plugin**

First go to Tools menu > Select Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates > Select one of the kotlin plugin & press download (stable or early access, i chose early access to solve this issue)

And finally change the kotlin version in build.gradle(Project:) according to the 
downloaded version

[image]

**Solution 2: Downgrade Plugin**

If your on **mac** then press: `Command + ,`
 to open preference, then select plugin & search for kotlin & uninstall it, it will rollback to previous version: 1.1.51

On **Windows machine**, press `Control + Alt + S` to open settings dialog, then select plugins & search for kotlin & uninstall it, it will rollback to previous version: 1.1.51

[image]

**Please Note:** Do not uncheck kotlin in plugins else it will disable kotlin & fail to recognise kotlin file & syntax

Comment: Instead of downgrading I updated the plugin and everything worked fine afterwards.

Comment: Upgrade to  AS 3.5, this error appears. Solution 1: no Kotlin menu. Solution 2: no   upgrade or downgrade.

Answer (score 2):

If upgrading doesn't help try downgrading

when i faces the same issue with Android studio 3.1 Canary 5 with Kotlin version v1.2.10-release-IJ2017.1-1 (latest version as on 15 dec 2017) I tried the above solution which didn't work so i just uninstalled the update and it reverted back to version 1.1.51 and that worked without any issue

Comment: For Android studio 3.1 Canary 5, I solved it by using the one from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin). Choose `AS3.1` version and install it manually.

Comment: thanks @swordsman it worked although in that link there is 1.2.0 while the latest one is 1.2.10

Comment: [1.2.10 already available for AS3.1 via IDE or direct download](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/update/41603)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in the latest kotlin plugin version **1.2.0-release-Studio3.0-1**. Try updating the kotlin plugin version.