# Kotlin plugin crashes Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I've update the Kotlin plugin to version 1.1.61 but Android studio don't start up with the new plugin.

The error:

```
Plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' failed to initialize and will be disabled.  Please restart Android Studio.

com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: Duplicate registration for EP: org.jetbrains.uast.uastLanguagePlugin: original plugin com.intellij, new plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

Comment: Same problem I have

Comment: @TeeTracker You can update the plugin to solve this issue. Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483040/5744335) for more info

Comment: The issue is gone. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plugin 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482853/plugin-org-jetbrains-kotlin-failed-to-initialize-and-will-be-disabled-please)

Answer (score 0):

```
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
```

please use this and after sync please re-start your android studio.